# Angular, component properties to service

Tags: angular, angular5

I have Angular component which is a dialog. Constructor looks like this:

```
class BigComponent {
    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<BigComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any)
    {
        this.userId = data.userId;
        this.authToken = data.authToken;
    }
}
```

This is how I show dialog (from the other part of the app):

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(BigComponent, {
  width: '600px',
  height: '300px',
  data: { userId: '12345', authToken: 'blabla' }
});
```

`data` is data injected into component, see [official documentation](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/dialog/dialog.md#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component). Basically, BigComponent is the part of the library of components. All components in this library will be shared across multiple applications. So `data` is something we need to pass to `BigComponent`, so it can operate: for example, make API calls without authentication issues.

But I also have multiple small components *inside* of a big component:

- SmallComponent1
- SmallComponent2
- SmallComponent3

There is also `BigComponent service` that can make queries to API. I need to use `BigComponent service`
in small components. But in order to do that, I need to pass `authToken` to the service from small component.

So what I do now is I am passing `authToken` this way:

```
BigComponent -> SmallComponent1 -> BigComponent service
BigComponent -> SmallComponent2 -> BigComponent service
BigComponent -> SmallComponent3 -> BigComponent service
```

It works, but I wonder if there is any way to initialize `BigComponent service` with `authToken`, so I don't
need this long chain?

P.S. I tried to inject `data` into the service the following way, but it didn't work:

```
export class BigComponentService {
    constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}
}
```

Error messages is:

> big.component.html:48 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[InjectionToken MatDialogData]: 
>     StaticInjectorError[InjectionToken MatDialogData]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData!

Comment: Can you please describe how you get this data? `data: { userId: '12345', authToken: 'blabla' }`

Comment: Where do you register BigComponent service? Can you set up an example on stackblitz?

Comment: @jcroll updated post and explained `data`

Comment: If you can inject data into BigComponent can you inject it into BigComponentService?

Comment: @yurzui `BigComponent service` is used only inside `BigComponent` (since there are some other small components, it is injected into small components).

Comment: @jcroll I tried, but I'm getting error message. Updated my post.

Comment: Put MatDialogData in the providers of appmodule and make it available application wide

Comment: Provide BigComponent service on BigComponent. See example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lk4wsw?file=main.ts

Comment: @jcroll @yurzui - it worked, thanks! I put `BigComponentService` into `providers` section inside `@Component` decorator for `BigComponent`. But I also had `BigComponentService` inside of `@NgModule` `providers`. Why these things are different? How to I know which providers to put into `@Component` decorator and which into `@NgModule`?